# Method to multiply any input number to the next whole number

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

My goal is to take any rational number as input into a function and output the next whole number that is a multiple of the input number. Is there a method to determine the rational expression for any such number? (i.e 1.5 as input would output 3)

Comment: What is the math equation to do what you want to do?

Comment: How about `result=(int(inputvar)+1)*inputvar`?

Comment: To solve this problem, you need to provide nominator and denominator of fraction (rational number) to exclude intrinsic floating point errors.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use a loop of brute force if you understand the math behind it. You can calculate the power of 10 needed to make the given number an integer first by deriving it from the number's exponent, and then calculate the least common multiples between the number and the aforementioned 10's power by dividing number with the greatest common divisor of the two:

```
from math import gcd
from decimal import Decimal

def whole_multiple(n):
    power = 10 ** -n.as_tuple().exponent
    n *= power
    return n // gcd(int(n), power)
```

so that:

```
whole_multiple(Decimal('-4.4'))
```

returns:

```
-22
```

Note that you have to pass to the function a `decimal.Decimal` object for it to calculate the exponent and to avoid floating point approximation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it slow and steady like this:

```py
def find_multiple(num):
    new_num = num
    while True:                    # until you hit a break statement
        new_num = round(new_num + num, 3)   # add the original number to the current number (next multiple), round because floating points are weird
        if new_num.is_integer():   # check if that is a whole number
            print(new_num)         # if so print and break the loop
            break
```

Example:

```py
>>> def find_multiple(num):
...     new_num = num
...     while True:
...         new_num = round(new_num + num, 3)
...         if new_num.is_integer():
...             print(new_num)
...             break
... 
>>> find_multiple(1.5)
3.0
>>> find_multiple(1.9)
19.0
>>> find_multiple(45.123)
45123.0
```

Comment: `>>> print(45.123, nextMultiple(45.123))
(45.123, 45123.0)
>>> find_multiple(45.123)
578201294.0`

Comment: Thanks @arunp9294 I didn't check for floating point errors at higher decimal places. I fixed it.

Comment: And yes it's slow, which I acknowledged initially. OP never responded with the math, so I gave them the most basic answer without using any more complex math concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. I am not sure whether answer is right!!!. But if it works very efficient solution I believe.

```
def nextMultiple(x):
    '''
        converting x to integer by multiplying by powers of 10
        eg: 1.5  as 15.0 = 1.5 * 10
        eg: 1.234 as  1234 = 1.234 * 1000
    '''
    m = len(str(x).split('.')[1])
    y = x * 10**(m)
    ans = y
    '''
        finding all prime factors of y and checking for condition to find the answer
    '''
    for i in range(2, int(y**0.5) + 1):
        if y % i == 0:
            c = round(i / x, m)
            if c == int(c) and i > x:
                ans = min(ans, i)
            o = y / i
            c = round(o / x, m)
            if c == int(c) and o > x:
                ans = min(ans, o)
    return ans

1.5 -> 3
3.13 -> 313.0
1.75 -> 7
10.1 -> 101.0
```